# How to read an arbitrary folder in a Universal app?

Tags: vb.net, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to learn to write Universal apps, and I'm starting out by trying to recreate another project I wrote in WinForms. I need to be able to read from log files in an arbitrary folder, and as I understand it I need to get the users permissions to access the folder. I should then store an access token so I can re-read that folder in future. By reading around I've managed to cobble together the following code:

```
Friend Async Function GetLogFolder() As Task(Of StorageFolder)
    Dim myLogFolder As StorageFolder
    If ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey("LogFolder") Then
        Dim sToken As String = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values("LogFolder")
        myLogFolder = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFileAsync(sToken)
    Else
        Dim myFolderPicker As FolderPicker = New FolderPicker
        myFolderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*")
        myLogFolder = Await myFolderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync

        Dim sToken As String = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(myLogFolder)
        ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.Add("LogFolder", sToken)
    End If
    Return myLogFolder
End Function
```

But it doesn't seem to work. At this stage I have a form containing just a TextBlock and Button. Clicking the Button calls a method that will parse all the *.log files in a given folder. The first thing it does is:

```
Dim myFolder As StorageFolder = GetLogFolder.Result
```

When the code runs, and I click the button, I get a folder browser dialog shown, but then everything freezes and I have to switch to Visual Studio and hit stop. I've probably made some silly error, but I can't figure out what it is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very likely not caused by the file access code itself, but by the way you use the asynchronous API.

Because the `GetLogFolder` method returns a `Task` of `StorageFolder`, you will need to await the result instead of getting it using the `Result` property. The reason is that the `async/await` pattern allows you to do **I/O work on a separate thread but return control back to the UI thread when finished**. What you are doing here is to call the `GetLogFolder` method, in which you let the user choose a folder using `FolderPicker`. **Here is the problem** - the user is presented with a folder picker while the control returns to your code and you query the `Result` property of the `Task` returned by the `GetLogFolder` method. Querying the `Result` property causes the UI thread to stop and wait until the `Task` is finished to get the result. Unfortunately, when the user picks the folder, the control wants to return to the UI thread to continue executing the rest of the `GetLogFolder` method and we have a **deadlock**. `Result` property stopped the UI thread to wait for the `Task` result and the `Task` waits for the UI thread to become available. Neither can continue so the app completely freezes.

The solution is quite simple - using the `async` / `await` keywords. You can read up more about them in VB.NET [here with a clear example](https://www.dotnetperls.com/async-vbnet).

In your case the first step would be to make the button's `Click` handler method `async` and then replace the code inside by the following:

```
Dim myFolder As StorageFolder = Await GetLogFolder
```